# username and password not accepted with pony gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, pony

im trying to implement a simple form for my ruby website using pony and i keep getting the error '535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted.' I've typed in my own gmail username and password in the correct fields.

code in pony.rb

```
Pony.options = {
:to => 'myusername',
:via => :smtp,: 
:via_options => {
:address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port                 => '587',
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:user_name            => 'myusername',
:password             => 'mypassword',
:authentication       => :plain, # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
:domain               => "localhost.localdomain" # the HELO domain provided by the    client to the server
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the WORKING code below. Just tested this with my gmail.

```
Pony.mail(:to => 'someone@acme.com', :via => :smtp, :via_options => 
{
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',                     
    :port => '587',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name => 'yourgmail@gmail.com',
    :password => 'yourpass',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :domain => "HELO",
 },
:subject => 'Your Subject goes here', :body => "bla bla bla or #{$body}",       
:attachments => {"yourfile.txt" => File.binread("c:/ruby193/bin/yourfile.txt")    
}
)
```

Best of luck Arvid let me know if you need further help!

Comment: hi i've implemented what you said but now i get the error :to is required

Comment: app/models/inquiry.rb:29:in `deliver'
app/controllers/inquiries_controller.rb:9:in `create'

Comment: def deliver
    return false unless valid?
    Pony.mail({
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>),
      :reply_to => email,
      :subject => "Website inquiry",
      :body => message,
      :html_body => simple_format(message)
    })
  end

Comment: def create
    (at)inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])
    if @inquiry.deliver
      render :thank_you
    else
      render :new
    end
  end